# Setting up Stoke's theorem integral for a Square surface

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I've looked everywhere online and through my textbooks but I can't find anything to clear up my confusion on this problem!

I've been giving a vector field $F = (yz,xy,xz)$ and the surface is simply the $1 \times 1$
square $0<x<1, 0<y<1$, at $z = 2$.

I have determined the $\text{curl}(F)$ as $(0,y-z,y-z)$, and the Normal Vector as $(0,0,1)$, but I can't figure out what I am supposed to use as the bounds for my integral.

In my mind it only makes sense to integrate $x$ and $y$ each from $0$ to $1$, but then
the expression being integrated is $y-z$, and that integral doesn't make any sense.

Am I supposed to simply substitute $2$ for $z$, since the square is located at $z = 2$?

Comment: Why do you think that the integral doesn't make sense? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Stokes you have surface integral = line integral:
$$\int_S\text{curl }F\,dS = \int_{\partial S}F.$$
For the *surface* integral you must parametrize the *surface*. For example:
$$\Phi(x,y) = (x,y,2).$$
Now, for this parametrization you must calculate the normal vector $N(x,y)$ and
$$
\int_S\text{curl }F\,dS =
\int_0^1\int_0^1\text{curl }F(\Phi(x,y))\cdot N(x,y)\,dxdy.
$$